# Acceso denegado en Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

Tengo este ajax

```
    $.ajax:{
        type:'GET',               
 url:"https://empresa1.sharepoint.com/teams/dev/plataforma1212/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Comprardores')/items",
                        async: false,
                        headers:{ 
                            "accept": "application/json",

                        },
                    }).done(function(response){
                        debugger
                    }).fail(function(response){
                        debugger
                        console.log("error");
                    });
```

El cual me debe trar un json de una lista de `SharePoint Online`

Pero me sale el siguiente error

```
code
:
"-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException"
message
:
{lang: "es-ES",…}
lang
:
"es-ES"
value
:
"Acceso denegado. No tiene el permiso necesario para realizar esta acción o tener acceso a este recurso." 
mira el error
```

**¿Que me puede estar generando este error?**

Comment: ¿Estarás intentando acceder a un servicio REST de forma anónima? Podrías encontrar solución [aquí](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/e9924aef-28df-43a4-8d79-a9d1532699c6/systemunauthorizedaccessexception-when-accessing-sharepoint-2013-rest-api?forum=sharepointsearch).

Comment: a mi me sale que no existe ese servicio. error 404

Comment: Todo indica que estas accediendo en forma anónima
¿Dónde esta tu JavaScript?
Si tu JavaScript estuviera en una pagina de elementos web o de publicación dentro de SharePoint y además el usuario tuviera permisos sobre la lista 'Comprardores' recibirás el JSON